# Paragraph tag blocking my div's onClick handler

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `<div>` that matches the size of its child `<p>`

I'm sending my div an onClick handler, but I can't click it because the `<p>` is blocking it.

I could send the onClick handler down another level, but it seems like there's probably a way to handle this.

```
class ExampleParent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
  }
  render() {
    <ExampleChild onClick={this.handleClick} />
  }
}

const ExampleChild = (props) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={(event) => props.handleClick(event)}>
      <ExampleGrandchild />
    </div>
  )
}

const ExampleGrandchild = () => {
  return (
    <p>hi</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: please share the code snippet

Comment: I think it would be best for you to update your question and include the relevant source code....

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I'm asking how to click a <div> that's underneath a <p> tag. Example posted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions

Add some css to prevent mouse events to be handled by your 'p'

```
p {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Add an 'onClick' prop to your ExampleGrandChild, then capture the onClick event on the 'p' and bubble it to the parent

```
const ExampleChild = (props) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={props.handleClick}>
      <ExampleGrandchild handleClick={props.handleClick} />
    </div>
  )
}

const ExampleGrandchild = (props) => {
  return (
    <p onClick={props.handleClick}>hi</p>
  )
}
```